# How to make my Master branch my Head, and create a new master

Tags: git

We started a new project, a couple of months ago.
We made a master branch, but actually used this as a develop/head branch. So this is full of commits you wouldn't want in your master. We actually have no head branch.

What I want, is to create a head branch, this should have all the commits of the current master branch, and then create a new master branch. I see some other examples of partly similar questions, but don't want to just try things and mess stuff up.

Comment: As long as you don't push or force-push you can try things out locally. You can always reset or clone the repo again to reset mistakes. Also you can try this out with a personal repo. After creating the new head branch you could `git rm` everything from the old master, commit that and then start that branch as a fresh, empty directory. At least this represents in the Git History what you have really done.

Answer (score 2):

Just pull the newest changes from the current `master`-branch by `git pull`. Now you are on the `Head`.

Then you must renaming the current `master`-branch to `develop`-branch (because there must not be branches with the same name) with `git branch -m develop` (but you must checkout the branch, where you want to rename).

Now you must push the *new*/*renamed* branch to remote with `git push origin -u develop` and remove the *old* one: `git push origin --delete master`.

Now you can create the *new* one with clean commit-history with simple `git checkout --orphan -b master` and push it to remote with `git push -u origin master`. (about `--orphan` flag, read the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---orphanltnew-branchgt)).

And now you can `git merge` from `develop`-branch to `master`-branch if you need it without having every single commit in the `master`-branch.

Comment: I am not sure with git but didn't you mean `git merge --squash`? Because he doesn't want all commits from `develop` in `master`.

Comment: No, but I revised the answer and added the `--orphan` flag when creating the branch. So the *new* created branch have no further commits, as can be seen from the documentation about it.